# Transform value date.now() "JS" to date format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

How to transform a date.now() JS value into a Date format

ex: 1590631408725 -> "05/27/2020 11:10:00"

Can i do this in c #?

Comment: How are you passing it to c#? If it's through data models then don't worry about it. C# will do that for you.

Comment: @Formula12 I get this value from an API, so I will tranform it into a date to insert in the bank

Comment: Can we see how your action method looks like?

Comment: That number appears to be milliseconds since the Unix Epoch, although it doesn't match up with the example human-readable date you've included. Furthermore, are you sure the bank requires this format and doesn't support ISO8601 format?

Comment: @John I was not aware of this fact, if I put the bank´s field in ISO8601 it would automatically stay as a date? tks!!

Comment: I would hope a bank would support ISO8601. Unless they have specified a format to use, I would assume this.

Answer (score 3):

We can use AddMilliseconds function of DateTime class to do this i guess. Maybe there are better ways but this is one way to do it.

```
var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(1590631408725);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
```

> Output: 05/28/2020 02:03:28